# Legacy recovery (V) values in Ethereum Signatures

Tags: digital-signature, ethereum, geth

Ethereum signatures must conform to the secp256k1 curve R, S and V values, requiring the V value must be either 27 or 28.

I was wondering what the legacy reason for two valid V values is?

Was this caused by the Ethereum classic hardfork? Do current wallet implementations only use one of them and the other is the legacy value that carried over?

See: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/55599ee95d4151a2502465e0afc7c47bd1acba77/internal/ethapi/api.go#L452-L459

```
// EcRecover returns the address for the account that was used to create the signature.
// Note, this function is compatible with eth_sign and personal_sign. As such it recovers
// the address of:
// hash = keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"${message length}${message})
// addr = ecrecover(hash, signature)
//
// Note, the signature must conform to the secp256k1 curve R, S and V values, where
// the V value must be be 27 or 28 for legacy reasons.
//
// https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_ecRecover
func (s *PrivateAccountAPI) EcRecover(ctx context.Context, data, sig hexutil.Bytes) (common.Address, error) {
    if len(sig) != 65 {
        return common.Address{}, fmt.Errorf("signature must be 65 bytes long")
    }
    if sig[64] != 27 && sig[64] != 28 {
        return common.Address{}, fmt.Errorf("invalid Ethereum signature (V is not 27 or 28)")
    }
    sig[64] -= 27 // Transform yellow paper V from 27/28 to 0/1

    rpk, err := crypto.Ecrecover(signHash(data), sig)
    if err != nil {
        return common.Address{}, err
    }
    pubKey := crypto.ToECDSAPub(rpk)
    recoveredAddr := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*pubKey)
    return recoveredAddr, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R and S aren't sufficient to recover the public key of the signer. V provides the extra bit of information required to disambiguate. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/what-does-v-r-s-in-eth-gettransactionbyhash-mean.